# $wpdb query for price in custom field value

Tags: query, wpdb, sql

A classifieds list site have only 3 criterias when searching products: the common search, category and region (for ZIP, city or full address) It's not enough and I really need to include a basic price system, so users can set a price range before searching.

Looking at the theme files, I found the function for different queries, based in one or more of those criterias. The smaller is the query for only category, so I'll take it as example:

```
elseif ($s_for == '' && $s_cat !== '' && $s_to == '') {
$query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
FROM
$wpdb->posts
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships
ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
WHERE
$wpdb->posts.post_type = '$cc_post_type'
AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '$cc_price' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$s_prc%')
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = '$cc_post_status'
AND ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = {$s_cat})
GROUP BY ID {$limit}";
}
```

Product prices are stored in custom fields (cc_price), so I tried...

```
AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '$cc_price' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$s_prc%')
```

...with a simple checkbox ($s_prc added to functions) with the value (just for testing purposes), but it doens't work, "query with no results". Is the query correct and I'm wrong in any other point?

Comment: Have you considered using `WP_Query` instead? Writing raw sql can be dangerous and bypasses a lot of the caching and optimisation mechanisms in place

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'cc_price' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%$s_prc%')
```

(Use cc_price instead of $cc_price)